# How can I transform rows to columns?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, transpose, flatten

I have this table with data below and need help because I don't know which formula can I use to convert the table into the desired one.

I don't know if it's possible with [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275), [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) or [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

Current Data Set:

| Date | E1 | E2 | E3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/01/2021 | 4,17% | 3,53% | 3,16% |
| 11/01/2021 | 4,40% | 3,69% | 3,58% |
| 18/01/2021 | 4,93% | 4,39% | 4,10% |

Expected Output:

| Date | Type | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/01/2021 | E1 | 4,17% |
| 4/01/2021 | E2 | 3,53% |
| 4/01/2021 | E3 | 3,16% |
| 11/01/2021 | E1 | 4,40% |
| 11/01/2021 | E2 | 3,69% |
| 11/01/2021 | E3 | 3,58% |
| 18/01/2021 | E1 | 4,93% |
| 18/01/2021 | E2 | 4,39% |
| 18/01/2021 | E3 | 4,10% |

[Data Set (Google Sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IRkFNkK-4Glt8Jj55xp-3jEK_Ff90d58XkU9RA1CqkI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
={"Date"\ "Type"\ "Metric"; INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(A2:A6&"×"&B1:L1&"×"&B2:L6); "×"); 
 "where Col3 is not null"; ))}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any method to format column 1 as date?

Comment: @JorgeGarcíaGarcía not sure whats your question... 1st colum is date already. you can check it with ISDATE function like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igIrf.png

Comment: Sorry, I mean if it can work like this: ={"Date"\ "Type"\ "Metric"; INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(DATEVALUE(A2:A)&"×"&B1:L1&"×"&B2:L6); "×"); 
 "where Col3 is not null"; ))}